# Solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(x + \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(x  + \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)$$  is equal to $\infty$?

I know that I couldn't use this:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(x  + \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x  + \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right)= \infty + 0 =\infty .$$

Comment: Here are the limit properties: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx

Comment: $\lvert\sin x\rvert\leqslant 1\implies\left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert}\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

For $x>1$:$$x+{\sin x\over x}>x-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Here $x\sim x+\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for sufficiently large values of $x.$ So they are same  at infinity.